# Where and in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am revising a Laravel 5 project for the first time in ages and even basics are failing me!

I have the following:

```
$logs = Log::where('my_id', '=', $my_id)->get();
```

I am trying to modify this so it gets results where the `my_id` matches but also where a variable `my_name` `$myname` matches.

I have read through the docs but still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just concat more `where` to have `AND` condition:

```
$logs = Log::where('my_id', '=', $my_id)->where('my_name', $my_name)->get();
```

If you need an `OR`:

```
$logs = Log::where('my_id', '=', $my_id)->orWhere('my_name', $my_name)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want both conditions ant the same time then just add this before the `get();`

```
->Where('my_name', $my_name)->get();
```

and if you only want 1 of the 2 conditions then add this before the `get();`

```
orWhere('my_name', $my_name)->get();
```

and if you want to get the first item that the DB returns then insted of `get();` use:
 `firstOrFail();`